# Criar "iframe" parecido com o facebook

Tags: javascript

Tentei procurar mais não sei nem por onde começar, quero criar um tipo de iframe para carregar o conteudo de outro site, mais não quero que seja iframe, quero que o conteudo desse outro site seja gerado dentro de uma DIV, um exemplo do que eu quero é o plugin de página do facebook, onde ele te da um script em javascript e uma div onde este plugin ira abrir.

Espero que minha duvida esteja clara!

---

Para oque eu queria ai em cima é chamado de widget, mais junto a minha pesquisa descobri que no meu caso vou ter que utilizar o iframe mesmo.

Segue uma ótima discussão sobre o assunto widget X Iframe: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535676/widget-iframe-versus-javascript

Comment: basicamente o que ele tem é uma api para transmitir os dados e um javascript para consumir na forma que citou.

Comment: Ainda estou em busca, mais pelo que entendi na pesquisa que estou fazendo isso que eu quero é um widget.